# Computing minimal surface numerically

Tags: optimization, minimal-surfaces

I am interested in computing a minimal surface on a domain $\Omega = [0,1]^{2}$. Specifically, I would like to fit some Ansatz function $z(x, y) = ax^{2}y^{2} + b x y + c x + d y$ with parameters $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}$ such that the resulting surface is minimal.

Naturally, without any constraints on these parameters I would expect the solution to be a plane (i.e., satisfying $a = b = 0$). So, lets say I have some additional constraint $v(a,b,c,d) = 0$ (sufficiently smooth, at least $C^{2}$), for example modeling behavior at the boundary precluding this solution

The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_surface) on minimal surfaces mentions Euler-Lagrange equations, i.e., additional PDE constraints. I believe that this would reduce the example problem to a nonlinear system of equations for the given $z$.

I would prefer instead to have a (smooth) objective based on $a, b, c, d$ instead, which could then be used to transform the problem into a (constrained) nonlinear programming problem. Can such an objective be derived (say from a variational formulation)?

Comment: Gradient descent could probably help. Instead of one gradient, you need at least two when you have constraints where at each step, you subtract the component of the change parallel to the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

After some literature research I arrived at the following:

First, the PDE constraints are likely not satisfied for all points $(x, y) \in \Omega$ for any choice of the parameters. The goal should be to compute an area as small as possible while satisfying constraint $v$. The area of the surface given by $z$ can be calculated as

$$
\int_{x \in [0,1]} \int_{y \in [0,1]} \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{\partial z}{ \partial x}\right)^{2} + \left(\frac{\partial z}{ \partial y} \right)^{2}} \mathrm{d}y \mathrm{d}x
$$

This objective is smooth in the parameters $a, b, c, d$, since the square root is bounded away from zero. To find a suitable solution, we can minimize this objective subjecting to the constraint $v(a,b,c,d) = 0$, yielding a nonlinear programming problem.